# K Nearest Neighbors First App. Error on drop function from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, knn

I was trying to make my first KNN App using sklearn, numpy and pandas. 
This is my code

I looked on pandas website but the documentation isn't fantastic.

```
import numpy as np  
from sklearn import preprocessing, model_selection, neighbors
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Projects\\machine learning\\classification\\K nearest Neighbors\\breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)

X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1))
y = np.array(df['class'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

And this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Projects/machine learning/classification/K nearest Neighbors/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 0))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3930, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3770, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3802, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4910, in drop
    '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['class'] not found in axis"
```

And "breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt" :

```
id, clump_thickness, unif_cell_size, unif_cell_shape, marg_adhesion, single_epidth_cell_size, bare_nuclei, bland_chrom, norm_nucleoli, mitoses, class
1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1002945,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
1015425,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
......
```

I don't know what is wrong. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What is `df.columns`? Is there whitespace before `class`: `' class'`?

Comment: Try to remove the brackets around 'class' in your `df.drop`

Comment: There was a space before ", class". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by removing all the spaces in txt file. try id,clump_thick,unif_cell_size,unif_cell_shape,marg_adhesion,sing_epith_cell_size,bare_nuclei,bland_chromatin,normal_nucl,mitoses,class(without spaces)

hope it helps!